# Assign workload to specific tasks based on an array value

Tags: c, task, openmp

I have a specific problem: I have a 2D matrix that contains some values that correspond to the tasks that should be executed in parallel. I would like to explicitly assign the workload to specific threads, which ID corresponds to the contents of this array. As a test, to understand what I should do, I have written the following simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>



int main(void)
{
int N=100; // Number of elements per dimension
int A[N][N], B[N][N]; // Matrices to work with
int i,j; // Loop indices
int nt; // Thread ID
int NT=4; //Number of threads

//Filling the arrays
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        A[i][j]=(i+j)%NT; //This is the value that corresponds to the task        we want to assign the job to
    
//Perform some operations   
#pragma omp parallel private(i,nt) num_threads(NT) 
{       
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {               
            nt = omp_get_thread_num();
            if(A[i][j]==nt)
            {
                B[i][j]=nt;
                //Some dummy operations to increase the load per thread
                for (int k = 0; k < 100000ULL; ++k);
            }
        }       
}

printf("\n\n\n\n");

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    printf("A[%d][%d]=%d goes to thread %d\n",i,j,A[i][j],B[i][j]);


return 1;
```

}

However, upon executing this, I am not sure that fulfils the initial purpose.
So the question is, how can explicitely assign a workload to specific threads? For example the first element of the matrix to be executed by thread 0, the second by thread 2, the third by thread 0, and so forth. From my undestanding, the double for loop should be executed outside the parallel region and not from every thread, to reduce the overall workload.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem is with your code that variable `j` should be private, so use `private(i,j,nt)` clause. It is even better to define your variables in their minimum required scope. Variables defined inside the parallel region will be private.
2. Another comment is that you have to check whether you got all the threads that you requested.

```
  if (NT != omp_get_num_threads()){
        // You have less threads than requested, 
        // handle this case here
    }
```

3. `const int nt = omp_get_thread_num();` should be before the `for` loop. It is enough to call this function once.
4. If your goal is to assign different indices (of a matrix) to threads in a round-robin manner:

```
thread   | indices assigned to the thread
-----------------------------------------
thread 0 | 0,0  0,4  0,8  etc...
thread 1 | 0,1  0,5  0,9  etc...
thread 2 | 0,2  0,6  0,10 etc...
thread 3 | 0,3  0,7  0,11 etc...
```

In this case you do not need a secondary array you can use something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{       
    const unsigned int NT = omp_get_num_threads();   // number of total threads
    const unsigned int nt = omp_get_thread_num();    // current thread
    for(unsigned int index = nt;index < N*N; index += NT)   
    {
        unsigned int i = index / N;
        unsigned int j = index % N;

        // Do whatever you have to do with indices i and j
        printf("Indices i=%d, j=%d goes to thread %d\n",i,j,nt);
    }
}
```

5. Performance: Without more details about what your real program does I cannot tell you anything about performance issues. E.g. writing to memory like `B[i][j]=...;` is a real nightmare in your case because of false sharing.

UPDATE: As pointed out by @Jim Cownie, the easiest solution is to use `schedule(static,1)` clause, because it distributes the work in a round-robin manner among threads. If you combine it with `collapse(2)` clause you just have to add one line to your serial code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(static,1) num_threads(NT) 
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {                           
        // Do whatever you have to do with indices i and j
        printf("Indices i=%d, j=%d goes to thread %d\n",i,j,omp_get_thread_num());
    }
```

There is, however, a serious drawback of this solution: the overheads are far much bigger in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will try your suggestions and come back

Comment: Re point 4: "If your goal is to assign different indices (of a matrix) to threads in a round-robin manner:",  this is much more easily achieved using a `#pragma omp for schedule(static,1)` rather than doing your own iteration partitioning.